problem of correspondence between scheduled shifts and actual shifts
The employee has a strong key.
On the one hand I record the shift calendar of each employee (shift calendar) and on the other hand I record the shifts that were actually carried out by the employee.
Now if employee "X" has two shifts, one on Monday morning and the other on Tuesday morning, and let's assume that he arrives on Monday evening. When he arrives, is he referring to the Monday morning shift where he arrived late or the Tuesday morning shift where he arrived anticipated?
There is no correspondence between the scheduled shifts and the shifts carried out
How can I add a match without creating redundancy?


Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Very unlikely that an employee would turn up more than 30 minutes before a shift!

There are two options

It is the clients decision how to categorise it. It is business logic.
Ask the employee which shift they are there for.

Maybe disallow consecutive shifts in the schedule.

I should add this correspondence between "shift calendar" and "actual shift" I thought of creating a 1:1 association between these two entities so in this way I know: the shift carried out by the employee corresponds to which scheduled shift, but I don't know if This way I create too much redundancy
